# Damages caused by inversely connected PCI-e power cable?

Tags: power-supply, atx, gpu

Recently, I used a 6-pin to 8-pin PCI-e convertor to power a graphics card (see the picture). After installation, each time I turned on the switch on the PSU and pressed the power button on the PC, the PSU only worked for a fraction of a second and turned off automatically. Then I realized that I had connected the 6-pin side of the converter cable in the wrong direction.

My question: Can I be sure that the GPU didn't receive -12 volts at all? The GPU works, but I wonder if any component might have been damaged due to this accident.

[image]

Comment: It's likely something's been damaged, you've basically applied -12 volts where you should have used +12.

Comment: Also, this isn't a PCIe power cable. PCIe has its own power, this is auxiliary power for power-hungry cards, and it's not part of the PCIe standard at all.

Comment: Also, these should be **very** hard to insert the wrong way around - the connector is mechanically impossible go insert the wrong way if you don't use massive amounts of force. This alone might also be cause of damage, to the cable.

Comment: @mmmm, Unfortunately the connectors weren't of good quality.

Comment: @mmmm A well-known flaw with Molex's Mini-Fit Jr connectors is that it's really easy to force a connector in the wrong way around. It may cause some mechanical damage to the connectors but it won't impede electrical contact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am highly doubtful any damage was done. What you did was connect system ground to the card's +12V input and +12 volt to the card's ground. All this did was short out +12V to ground through the card's connector and edge connector. Although a lot of current could have passed through the card traces, it would have been for a very short time before the PS went into over-current shutdown.

Basically, if you didn't blow any traces (which it seems you didn't since the card works), I don't see how the card could be damaged.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just checked the place of the 8-pin connector on PCB visually and also by continuity check. It seems you are right and I hope you're right. :)